# VSTS Minimatch pattern to exclude .git folder

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, minimatch

I'm using VSTS and the build task **FTP Upload**. When the files and folders are uploaded to my FTP server the **.git** folder is always copied to the server too.
I tried to exclude the **.git** folder with file pattern like following:

```
**
!(**/.git/**)
```

I don't know why it does not work but is there any way to tell the task with minimatch pattern to exclude folder explicitly?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The minimatch pattern for the file patterns option in FTP Upload task only can **exclude the folders**. Such as if you use the `!**\.git\**` as File patterns, it will only remove the `.git` folder and the subfolders in it, but the files in these folder still upload to FTP server.

If you don’t want the `.git` folder (including the files in it) to be uploaded to FTP, you can add a **Copy Files task** before FTP Upload task. Detail settings as below:

#### Copy Files task

Source Folder： `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`

Contents:

```
**
!**\.git\**
```

Target Folder: `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\upload`

#### FTP Upload task

You just need to change below settings,

Source folder: `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\upload`

File patterns: `**`

Now exclude the files in `.git` folder, all the files and folders are upload to FTP server.

Comment: that indeed seems to solve the issue, I find the docs to be a bit misleading in this case tbh